# swift flash or blink 2 random colors when the button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, macos

hello this app currently starts out with a blank black screen and when u press the button in the middle of the screen it changes the background to a random color. I would like to start out with a message in the black screen saying " warning may cause seizure" and have the message dissapear once the button is pressed for the first time  and the background will flash or blink 2 random colors forever until the button is pressed again. when the button is pressed again it will blink or flash 2 new random colors and so on. I hope this is not confusing, its really easy I just can't figure it out :( please help

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [
    .systemYellow,
    .systemGreen,
    .systemPurple,
    .systemPink,
    .systemRed,
    .systemBlue,
    .systemOrange,
    .black,.gray
        
    
    ]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
}

@IBAction func didTapButton() {
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/12, delay:0, options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
           self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
           self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()           }, completion: nil)
    
}
```

}

Comment: Remove your animation option.

Comment: I did that but the background doesn't continue to flash? can u help me plz :(

Comment: Remove this `options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse]` and set it to `[]` or if possible set it to `nil`

Comment: Oh give me just a moment. It's not blinking and you want it to blink. One moment.

Comment: god bless you I will wait

Answer (score 0):

First setup a timer, since you'll be running the animation forever until the button is clicked. In the ViewDidLoad() this will start the timer.

```
var timer: customTimer = Timer()
var isAnimating = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    startAnimation()
    
}
```

We start the timer with `startAnimation()` and it executes the code every 1 second. This is `double` so you can make it fractions of seconds, eg `0.1` or `0.001` mind you the lower the number the more resource intensive.

```
func startAnimation() {
        customTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/12, delay:0, options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
               self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
               self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()           }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Timers can be invalidated, ergo "Stopped" whenever you need to stop them. Just make sure that you don't have a nil timer or it will crash. You could create a flag that has `var animationRunning = false` then switch it to make the button turn animations on/off.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped() {
    isAnimating = !isAnimating
    if isAnimating { customTimer.start() }
    else { customTimer.invalidate() }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you for your time ! let me see if it works :)

Comment: There may be some syntax errors in there, I literally did all that off the top of my head.

Comment: I am getting an error code with the custom timer :( is there anyway u can posy the whole code ? that would help a lot

Comment: oh I see no worries thank you for your time this helped a lot!

Comment: something with the custom timer